# Invalid taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am adding full code. Please review my code, to find out the reason of error(Invalid taxonomy).I am using this code in child theme function file, not in plugin file.

```
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');
    function portfolio_register() {
        $labels = array(
                    'name' => _x( 'Portfolio', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Portfolio Item', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio item'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio Item'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Item'),
            'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item'),
            'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio'),
            'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
                );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => null,
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
          ); 
        register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
            add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy' );
    register_taxonomy(
            "skills", 
            array("portfolio"), 
            array("hierarchical" => true, 
                "label" => "skills", 
                "singular_label" => "Skill", 
                "rewrite" => true)
            );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: "Please review my code, to find out the reason of error" ... hmm. Try to reword you question so you list what you are trying to achieve, which errors you are getting, and what you've tried including the code (the very last part is covered),

Comment: first you don't need  to  use   `add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy' );` twice second when are you getting this error? i just tried your code and it's working fine on my local machine, and useually this error caused by `get_terms()` so are you calling the terms somewhere else in your code

Comment: @kashalo, Please see error link: https://imgur.com/a/2ZHWio8

Comment: @kashalo, Error will come when you will enter in browser search bar to reload this page.

Comment: there is no error in this particular code so your code working on this link https://imgur.com/a/pkJDAc3 , you need to find out if your theme or some plugin manipulating the terms some how

Comment: one thing you can do remove the `register_taxonomy` from your function and add separated function for that and hooked it after everything is loaded using the following hook `add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'your callback function' );`

Comment: $Kashalo, done but same result, thanks for comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179529/discussion-between-kashalo-and-super-model).

Comment: Thanks $Kashalo, issue resolved by: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108576/133699